# Should I use Fedora Server on a computer hosting VMs?

Tags: fedora

I have a computer that will host multiple VMs for different users. This setup is for testing environment. Every tester can have their own VM as a test environment. If they have a test I will create a VM for them and they can remote to that VM. I know I can do that using Fedora workstation but would it benefit me more when I install fedora server? What are the packages in fedora server that's not in the workstation that can benefit my situation more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer: Fedora workstation and Fedora server have access to all of the same packages. What differentiates them is the choice of packages that are included by default.

The workstation comes pre-installed with a graphical user interface (GUI) and commonly used workstation programs (office suites, games, etc).

The server ships without a GUI - it ships with an OpenSSH server set up and the option to include a few basic server essentials (web servers, mail servers, etc) out of the box.

If you are comfortable with a command line, I would recommend the server option. If you'd prefer to use graphical applications, go with the workstation. The important thing here is that either option does not limit your choices in terms of what you can install down the road.